# Asymmetry of string::find_first_of and string::find_last_of

Tags: c++

With the member function string::find_first_of in the C++ standard library you can search in the empty substring:

```
 s.find_first_of(c, s.size())
```

or

```
s.find_first_of(c, string::npos)
```

But you cannot search in the empty substring with `string::find_last_of`; the next call will search in a substring containing (only) the first character:

```
 s.find_last_of(c, 0)
```

I think it is an imperfection of the C++ standard library, isn't it?

Comment: what is `c` in this case? `std::string`, `char`, `cont char*`? Also I can't see anything in the doc suggesting that `npos` is valid input for the position parameter.

Comment: @111111: `npos` is valid input. In fact, many string functions use it as default argument for position parameter.

Comment: It does not matter, but I meant `char`.

Answer (score 4):

I don't see any asymmetry here. In fact quite the opposite, it appears to be perfectly symmetrical. Just think of `find_first_of` as search to the *right* from some starting position, while `find_last_of` is a search to the *left* from some starting position.

The name `find_last_of` has a misleading quality about it: it implies a natural *forward* search, except that we return the last occurrence instead of the first one. However, with bidirectional sequences one can ignore the "forward" nature of the name and think of it as of as *backward* search. Backward search also returns the first occurrence, it just proceeds *to the left* from the starting point. From this point of view, the function is symmetrical with `find_first_of`.

**EDIT:** After reading your comments I finally understand your point. So, the problem is that the current semantics of `pos` parameter makes it impossible to specify *empty* search region for `find_last_of`. Yes, that makes sense. I agree, that is indeed something that can be seen as inconsistency in `find_last_of` design.

For consistency purposes, I would actually expect `find_last_of` to be non-inclusive with respect to `pos` value. In that case the specification of the target position of `xpos` returned by `find_last_of` would be

> xpos < pos and xpos < size();

In that case `s.find_last_of(c, 0)` would search an empty prefix, while `s.find_last_of(c, s.size())` would search the entire string.

However the standard says

> xpos <= pos and xpos < size();

I don't really know why they decided to give the `pos` parameter such inclusive meaning. Probably they thought that it would make it easier to understand.

Comment: Forward or backward, the both functions search in a **prefix** of the string, and not in a suffix. In this respect, they should be equal.

Comment: @Igor I.: I'm not sure what you mean. You meant they *should be* searching in the prefix? Because the way things are now, that's not the case. `find_first_of` searches in the **suffix** of the string, i.e. it searches forward after `pos`. `find_last_of` searches in the **prefix** of the string, i.e. it essentially searches backward before `pos`.

Comment: Sorry, I was doubly wrong. First, I had to write "in a **suffix**, and not in a prefix"; and second, I had to point that in the case of `find_last_of` it is a suffix of the reversed string (because `find_last_of` search backwards). But conceptually the both cases should be handled equally, and if an empty suffix is allowed for `find_first_of`, it should be allowed for `find_last_of` too.